# Using Jade for Angular templates in a MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, pug, mean-stack

I can't seem to find this on Google.  I'm going through the Getting MEAN tutorial.  In the first part it's an Express app using Jade. Then the author adds on Angular and he uses HTML for the templates. My question is how can I use Jade templates for Angular?

Comment: Personally would not have server side templating with angular, can setup a json API with node and express and write the client as a consumer of the json API.

Comment: Disagree completely with this opinion, using pug with client-side frameworks gives a lot of power to the developer and a very fast response time for the user.